# Samsung TV doesn't react to Wake on LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, samsung-smart-tv, wake-on-lan

I am trying to setup a NodeJs app that will control my Samsung SmartTv. So far I succeeded in controlling everything except switching it ON. For that I want to use Wake on LAN.

The problem is, when I send the TV the magic packet, the TV doesn't react to it regardless of how I send the packet. I tried wake on lan software, the npm 'wake_on_lan', 'wake-on-lan-node' and 'node-wol' packages.

I'm on a MacBookAir under Mac OS X 10.13.6, and my TV is a 'HG49EE690' which is one of the HotelTv models from 2014 to 2016 with the encryption protocol for remote control via a WebSocket.

I have the TV connected via Ethernet to the same network I am using, and I know from the Samsung's specifications that the TV has Wake on LAN ability.

Comment: Did you enable wake up on LAN in the BIOS? Also, I think this question is off-topic.

Comment: Well if you know how to enable it on a Smart Tv I'd be grateful

Comment: @1010101: could you give an explaination why this question might be off-topic? (imho it is NOT off-topic because it relates to a certain technology/framework..)

Comment: @ClementDa I don't know, unfortunately. But since your NodeJs App is working as expected but the magic packet you send is not responding, it seems that the problem is some sort of a Smart TV configuration.

Comment: @iLuvLogix I might be wrong (hence the "think"), so this is left for users with higher reputation to decide. From my understanding to the question, the OP isn't having trouble with the technology/framework (_"So far I succeeded in controlling everything except switching it ON"_) but with the SmartTV network settings itself. (My bad, should've explained myself earlier)

Comment: I spent the whole day trying to figure out where to enable WOL on a Samsung TV but I can't find anyone who had the same problem.

Comment: @ClementDa can you share the code for the wake on lan logic? a potential issue is that you might need to use the broadcast address rather than the ip address of the tv.

Comment: @Clement Da Did you find a solution for this? My Samsung TV doesn't seem to respond to WOL also

Comment: i have the exact same problem with my UE60J6289